# How to Reference List of Dicitionaries from One Class to Another?

Tags: python, reference, self

I am currently working on an inventory system and trying to implement a class that serves as a "fast fact finer" for my database, which is managed by my Database Management class.

The csv file looks like this:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
class DataBase_Management(object):
   
   def __init__(self):
       self.result = []


   def make_dict_items(self):
       with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
           reader = csv.reader(fp)
           labels = next(reader, None)
           result = []
           for row in reader:
               if row:
                   row[0] = int(row[0])
                   row[1] = float(row[1])
                   row[2] = int(row[2])
                   pairs = zip(labels, row)
                   self.result.append(dict(pairs))
   
   def get_listofdicts(self):
       return self.result
```

The above class manages the list of dicts, through several methods that add items, delete items, etc (not included for simplicity to question).

I also have this class I am working on:

```
class DB_Fact_Finder():

    def __init__(self, management):
        self.management = management

    def return_item_num(self, item):
        items = self.management.get_listodicts()
        return items[item]["Item #"]

    def return_price(self, item):
        items = self.management.get_listodicts()
        return items[item]["Price "]
        

    def return_name(self, item):
        items = self.management.get_listodicts()
        return self.result[item]["Name"]
        

    def return_qnty(self, item):
         items = self.management.get_listodicts()
         return self.result[item]["Quantity"]
```

Basically, I want the DB_Fact_Finder class to be able to look at the self.result list of dictionaries defined in the management class, and be able to find specific items such as price, quantity, etc. I tried to implement this in the above code, but feel like I am missing something key to be able to reference the self.result from another class?. How would I do this?

Comment: This looks like it will work. What's the problem? The only major thing I see is you never call `make_dict_items` in `DB_Fact_Finder`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried running a test in one of my classes that is not shown here printing an specific items price, and get the following error TypeError: DB_Fact_Finder.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'management'  Also, why would I need to call make_dict_items again in the new class? Doesnt the return always reference the current list o f dictionaries?

Comment: The error means you need to pass an instance of `DataBase_Management` when you create a  `DB_Fact_Finder` instance. It's clear that `management` is a required arg of the `__init__` method

Comment: @crunker99 How would I pass the instance? Sorta new to coding and am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage: create instance of `DataBase_Management`, populate `results` list, pass to `DB_Fact_Finder`

```py
db_management = DataBase_Management()
db_management.make_dict_items()
db_fact_finder = DB_Fact_Finder(db_management)

# example usage:
price_1 = db_fact_finder.return_price(0)
print(item_num)
# 5.99
```

Note there are some problems with the methods of `DB_Fact_Finder`.

This does not work:

```py
def return_name(self, item):
        items = self.management.get_listodicts()
        return self.result[item]["Name"]
```

There will not be a `self.results` property of a `DB_Fact_Finder` object as you have the class defined. Same issue exists in `def return_qnty`

The first two methods are calling `self.management` correctly.

Comment: db_management = DataBase_Management()
db_management.make_dict_items()
db_fact_finder = DB_Fact_Finder(db_management)                                                                                 Would these go in the DB_Fact_Finder class? I am confused on where this would go?

Comment: You haven't given an example of where these classes are actually used. But that's where it would go.

Comment: Got it, I just needed to add the code you mentioned into the class with the method where I was trying to print the price! Thank you

Comment: Also, something I had to fix was to update items = self.management.get_listodicts() to items = self.management.get_listofdicts(), forgot to put of instead of o